Возникают исключения при попытке управления данными через Entity Framework
Есть класс контекста данных ApplicationContext.cs:
internal class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Contact>? Contacts { get; set; }
    
    public DbSet<PhoneType>? PhoneTypes { get; set; }
    
    public DbSet<ContactInfo>? ContactsInfo { get; set; }
    
    public ApplicationContext() : base("Data Source=XXX;Initial Catalog=ContactsNotebookDB;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True")
    {
        Database.CreateIfNotExists();
    }
}

Детализация записей:
Contact.cs:
internal class Contact : IDatabase
{
    public required int ID { get; set; }
    
    public required string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    
    public int? PhoneTypeID { get; set; }
    
    public required int ContactInfoID { get; set; }
}

ContactInfo.cs:
[Table("ContactsInfo")] // обязательное явное указание названия таблицы
(по умолчанию EF читает как "ContactInfoes")
internal class ContactInfo : IDatabase
{
    public required int ID { get; set; }
    
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    
    public required string Surname { get; set; }
    
    public string? Patronymic { get; set; }
    
    public required char Sex { get; set; }
}

Когда я пытаюсь сохранить данные в коде одного из View, то возникает исключение:
using ApplicationContext ApplicationContext = new();

int ContactsInfoMaxID = ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo.Count();
int ContactsMaxID = ApplicationContext.Contacts.Count();

ContactInfo ContactInfo = new()
{
    ID = ContactsInfoMaxID + 1,
    Name = NameTextBox.Text,
    Surname = SurnameTextBox.Text,
    Patronymic = Patronymic,
    Sex = SexComboBox.Text[0]
};

Contact Contact = new()
{
    ID = ContactsMaxID + 1,
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumberTextBox.Text,
    PhoneTypeID = PhoneTypeComboBox.SelectedIndex,
    ContactInfoID = ContactInfo.ID,
};

ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo.Add(ContactInfo);
ApplicationContext.Contacts.Add(Contact);

ApplicationContext.SaveChanges(); // тут возникает исключение при сохранении


Строка ApplicationContext.SaveChanges(); вызывает следующее исключение:
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."

И 2 внутренних исключения:
UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.

SqlException: Не удалось вставить значение NULL в столбец "ID", таблицы "ContactsNotebookDB.dbo.Contacts"; в столбце запрещены значения NULL. Ошибка в INSERT.
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.

Обновление проблемы:
При попытке удаление записи из БД также возникает исключение.
Фрагмент кода ViewModel с методом, который пытается удалить данные:
/// <summary>
/// Команда удаления контакта
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parameter"></param>
private void DeleteContact(object parameter)
{
    MessageBoxResult DeleteContactMessageBoxResult = MessageBox.Show($"Внимание, вы действительно хотите удалить следующий контакт:\n\n{PhoneNumber}\n{Surname} {Name}{(Patronymic == "—" ? null : " " + Patronymic)}?", "Удаление контакта", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
    
    if (DeleteContactMessageBoxResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    {
        using ApplicationContext ApplicationContext = new();
        
        bool IsContactInUse = ApplicationContext.Contacts.Any(Contact => Contact.ContactInfoID == ID);
        
        if (!IsContactInUse)
        {
            ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo?.Remove(ContactInfo);
        }
        
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Текущий используется в Contact и не может быть удален.");
        }
        
        ApplicationContext.Contacts?.Remove(Contact);
        ApplicationContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}


Строка ApplicationContext.Contacts?.Remove(Contact); вызывает исключение:
System.InvalidOperationException: "The object cannot be deleted because it was not found in the ObjectStateManager."

Дополнительная информация:

Версия Entity Framework — 6.5.1;
Я уверен в правильности записей, вносимых в БД, потому что во время проверки через отладку записи вносятся в ApplicationContext:



Уже странно, что ContactsInfo возвращает только 1 новую запись, в то время как Contacts возвращает все записи + новую запись (она, кстати, почему-то помещается наверх таблицы).
Даже если я явно задам Null-данные, запись по прежнему не будет вноситься в БД, отображая то же исключение.
P. S. Я увидел 0 в добавляемой записи Contacts (атрибут PhoneTypeID), исправил его на 1, но на ошибке это не отразилось.

Выражение ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo.Sql в отладке возвращает значение:
SELECT
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID],
[Extent1].[Name] AS [Name],
[Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname],
[Extent1].[Patronymic] AS [Patronymic]
FROM [dbo].[ContactsInfo] AS [Extent1]


То есть тут почему-то отсутствует столбец Sex из таблицы БД.

Я пересоздавал БД, создавал дубликат БД без записей, без связей, у которого не было первичных ключей и обязательных полей, но в таком случае вылетает другое исключение:
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: "Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions."


И внутреннее:
OptimisticConcurrencyException: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.


Струткура таблиц в БД MS SQL:

ContactsInfo:

Contacts:


Если попробовать добавить запись не в Contacts, а в ContactsInfo и попытаться сохранить изменения, то возникает то же исключение, но с другим внутренним исключением:
SqlException: Не удалось вставить значение NULL в столбец "Sex", таблицы "ContactsNotebookDB.dbo.ContactsInfo"; в столбце запрещены значения NULL. Ошибка в INSERT.
Выполнение данной инструкции было прервано.

А, ну из очевидного, конечно, ApplicationContext получает данные из БД, ведь он возвращает верные значения при обращении к нему (кол-во таблиц и их записи), поэтому проблема не в подключении.


Обновлено:

Непонятно почему строка ApplicationContext.Contacts?.Remove(Contact); вызывает исключение, ведь данные из БД по контактам загрузились в ApplicationContext (хотя проверка в отладке работает 50/50: либо отображает загруженные Contacts, либо пишет, что их кол-во — 0).


Укажите версию EF. / Ох, опять ручное манипулирование ID... Зарубите себе на носу: айдишники не для человека, а для компьютера! Задайте автоинкремент и забудьте о проблемах.

ID = ContactsInfoMaxID + 1, вот такое делать не надо, пользуйтесь автоинкрементом в БД. А то потом удалите одну запись где нибудь и всё у вас сломается.

@AlexanderPetrov, версия EF — 6.5.1. По поводу автоинкрементного ID, да, так будет лучше, но это не меняет сути проблемы

DbUpdateException явно говорит о том, что происходит не сохранение новой сущности, а обновление, по той причине, что заданный айдишник совпадает с уже существующим в БД. Вы пишите, что пересоздавали БД. Как? В коде я вижу CreateIfNotExists, но не вижу действительного удаления. Очевидно, старые данные остались в таблице. Вот и совпадает вручную заданный ID с существующим.

@AlexanderPetrov, пересоздавал БД в MS SQL, т. к. думал, что проблема может быть на уровне БД. Но также в коде перед внесением изменений прописывал Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<ApplicationContext>());.
По поводу совпадения ID — как он может совпадать, если в БД 8 записей у ContactsInfo, а я добавляю новую запись с ID = 9? В отладке ID = 9.

На скринах я вижу одну-единственную запись в таблице ContactsInfo. Впрочем, вы смотрите коллекцию Local, которая в памяти и может не совпадать с тем, что на диске.

Короче, убирайте строки int ContactsInfoMaxID = ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo.Count(); int ContactsMaxID = ApplicationContext.Contacts.Count();. Убирайте ID = ContactsInfoMaxID + 1, и ID = ContactsMaxID + 1, (оставьте айдишники неинициализированными, БД сама их задаст).

Создайте в сущности Contact навигационное свойство public int ContactInfo {get; set;}. Убирайте ContactInfoID = ContactInfo.ID,. Вместо этого задавайте ContactInfo = contactInfo (свойству присвойте сущность; чтобы не было путаницы именуйте локальные переменные с маленькой буквы).

И пора бы отказаться от устарвшего EF 6. Переходите на EF Core. Последняя стабильная версия EF 8. В ноябре уже выйдет EF 9.

Предложение @Alexander Petrov в комментариях:

Короче, убирайте строки int ContactsInfoMaxID = ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo.Count(); int ContactsMaxID = ApplicationContext.Contacts.Count();. Убирайте ID = ContactsInfoMaxID + 1, и ID = ContactsMaxID + 1, (оставьте айдишники неинициализированными, БД сама их задаст).

было прямо в яблочко! Вот только я воспринимал это как совет, но никак не думал, что это будет единственным способом решения данной проблемы. Кстати, применяя его в первый раз почему-то мне не удавалось решить проблему.
Как ни странно, начну с починки возможности удаления записи из БД, ведь она происходит легче.
Для этого нужно просто прикрепить удаляемую запись с помощью метода Attach() перед удалением с помощью Remove().
Например:
ApplicationContext.Contacts.Attach(Contact); // прикрепляем удаляемый объект к контексту
ApplicationContext.Contacts.Remove(Contact);
await ApplicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();

Но Attach() нужен лишь в том случае, если:

объект был получен из другого источника (например, из кэша, с фронтенда или другого контекста);
объект был создан вручную и необходимо удалить или обновить его в базе данных.

То есть если объект был получен из базы данных через текущий контекст (через методы вроде Find, FirstOrDefault, LINQ-запросы и т. д.), то в таком случае объект уже отслеживается и использование метода Attach() не требуется.
И всё. Этого достаточно для того, чтобы записи удалялись. И никаких "танцев с бубном" по типу изменения первичного ключа на автоинкрементный. Я не говорю, что автоинкрементный ключ — плохо. Я лишь говорю то, что Remove() хотя бы предоставляет свободу выбора.
Сразу говорю, ответ взят отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791149/the-object-cannot-be-deleted-because-it-was-not-found-in-the-objectstatemanager.
Чего не скажешь о добавлении записи в БД с помощью метода Add()...
Для того, чтобы можно было вносить новые записи в БД нужно... нет, не изменить код, а изменить архитектуру в БД.
А именно указать ключу ID то, что он автоинкрементный. И всё!
То есть в проекте таблицы в MS SQL изменить параметр поля ID следующим образом:

Итоговая версия кода:
ContactInfo ContactInfo = new()
{
    Name = NameTextBox.Text,
    Surname = SurnameTextBox.Text,
    Patronymic = Patronymic,
    Sex = SexComboBox.Text/*[0]*/
};

Contact Contact = new()
{
    PhoneNumber = PhoneNumberTextBox.Text,
    PhoneTypeID = PhoneTypeID,
    ContactInfoID = ContactInfo.ID
};

using ApplicationContext ApplicationContext = new();

if (ContactViewModel != null) // если редактируем запись
{
    Contact? DBContact = ApplicationContext.Contacts?.FirstOrDefault(Contact => Contact.ID == ContactViewModel.ID);
    ContactInfo? DBContactInfo = ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo?.FirstOrDefault(Contact => Contact.ID == ContactViewModel.ContactInfo.ID);
    
    if (DBContactInfo != null)
    {
        DBContactInfo.Name = ContactInfo.Name;
        DBContactInfo.Surname = ContactInfo.Surname;
        DBContactInfo.Patronymic = ContactInfo.Patronymic;
        DBContactInfo.Sex = ContactInfo.Sex;
    }
    
    if (DBContact != null)
    {
        DBContact.PhoneNumber = Contact.PhoneNumber;
        DBContact.PhoneTypeID = Contact.PhoneTypeID;
    }
}

else // если создаём новую запись
{
    ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo?.Add(ContactInfo);
    await ApplicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    
    Contact.ContactInfoID = ContactInfo.ID;
    ApplicationContext.Contacts?.Add(Contact);
}

await ApplicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();

Обновлено:
Важно! Обратите внимание на то, что если у вас есть подчинённая сущность (у меня в данном случае свойство ContactInfoID у Contact, зависящее от ID у ContactInfo), то перед добавлением новых записей в БД нужно сохранять сущности поочерёдно:
ApplicationContext.ContactsInfo?.Add(ContactInfo);
await ApplicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();

Contact.ContactInfoID = ContactInfo.ID;
ApplicationContext.Contacts?.Add(Contact);
await ApplicationContext.SaveChangesAsync();

Потому-что в момент инициализации ID у ContactInfo равно 0 — ему присвоется ID только после добавления в БД! Особенно явно это видно если в БД выставлены ограничения по внешним ключам:



В этом коде огромное количество вызовов в БД. Все эти FirstOrDefault и SaveChangesAsync. В реальном нагруженном проекте это повесит БД. / Создайте в сущности Contact навигационное свойство public ContactInfo ContactInfo {get; set;} (в комментарии под вопросом у меня опечатка).
